# Using gulp-watch with babel.js

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, babeljs

Below is a Gulp ES6 transpilation task.  It works fine, but I'm trying to replace gulp.watch with the gulp-watch plugin so new files will be caught.  The problem is that gulp-watch isn't giving me what gulp.watch does in the callback, and I'm not sure what to do about it.

Here's my original working task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    gprint = require('gulp-print'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.watch('../**/**-es6.js', function(obj){
        if (obj.type === 'changed') {
            gulp.src(obj.path, { base: './' })
                .pipe(plumber({
                    errorHandler: function (error) { /* elided */ }
                }))
                .pipe(babel())
                .pipe(rename(function (path) {
                    path.basename = path.basename.replace(/-es6$/, '');
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
                .pipe(gprint(function(filePath){ return "File processed: " + filePath; }));
        }
    });
});
```

And here's all that I have so far with gulp-watch:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    gprint = require('gulp-print'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel'),
    gWatch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gWatch('../**/**-es6.js', function(obj){
        console.log('watch event - ', Object.keys(obj).join(','));
        console.log('watch event - ', obj.event);
        console.log('watch event - ', obj.base);

        return;
        if (obj.type === 'changed') {
            gulp.src(obj.path, { base: './' })
                .pipe(plumber({
                    errorHandler: function (error) { /* elided */ }
                }))
                .pipe(babel())
                .pipe(rename(function (path) {
                    path.basename = path.basename.replace(/-es6$/, '');
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
                .pipe(gprint(function(filePath){ return "File processed: " + filePath; }));
        }
    });
});
```

The output of the logging is this:

> watch event -  history,cwd,base,stat,_contents,event
>
> watch event -  change
>
> watch event -  ..

How do I get gulp-watch to give me the info I had before, or, how can I change my task's code to get this working again with gulp-watch?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `obj.event === 'change'`?

Comment: @Ben - sure - I can get over *that* hump, but I'm still missing obj.path, so I can identify the specific file for gulp.src.  I should also note that I'm relatively new to Gulp - so the answer may very well be simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [tests](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/blob/master/test/callback.js#L25), `obj.relative` should contain the relative filename, and `obj.path` will still hold the absolute file path, just as it did in your original code. Also, the callback accepts a Vinyl object, which is documented here: https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl

You probably can't see them in your logs since `Object.keys` doesn't enumerate properties in the prototype chain.

Using a `for..in` loop, you should be able to see all the properties.

Comment: Thank you so much - I need to step away for a few hours - but I'll give this a look as soon as I'm back and upvote and accept if it works.

Comment: Thanks a ton - I made a small edit - looks like I should have just left my original code alone - I wish this were documented better!

Comment: Eh - I guess the documentation I needed was here :-| https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl